# PHP switch case HTML multiple select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have HTML multiple select box:

```
<option value="1">First selection item</option>
<option value="2">Another selection item</option>
<option value="3">Third selection item</option>
```

By jQuery I'm sending POST request to PHP, and then I'm checking.. :

```
switch( $value ) :
    case 1:
        $firstItem = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        $anotherItem = 1;
        break;
    case 3:
        $thirdItem = 1;
        break;
    default:
        $firstItem = $anotherItem = $thirdItem = 0;
endswitch;
```

Then...

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare( "UPDATE myTable SET firstItem = ?, anotherItem = ?, thirdItem = ? WHERE Nickname = ?" );
$stmt->execute( array( $firstItem, $anotherItem, $thirdItem, $nickname ) );
```

And I have no idea why code isn't working. For example if I select only `option with value = 2` Then `$firstItem = NULL` and `$thirdItem = NULL`. I think it would be stupid to make a lot of if's with every possible selection. I need to make this:

> option 1 selected --- $firstItem = 1, $anotherItem = $thirdItem = 0;
>
> option 1,2 selected - $firstItem = $anotherItem = 1, $thirdItem = 0;

And yes.. If any selected ( `$value = 0` ) then `$firstItem = $anotherItem = $thirdItem = 0`

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something is wrong, your switch will go to only *one* case and that is fine if you the user can select only one option, but the functionality you ask for means that the user can select multiple values at the same time which means that `$value` is not an `int` but maybe an array

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood the issue, but what about initializing the values with 0 before the switch-case. The default case will not be hit when f. i. case 2 is executed. Does that help?
And yes... The switch case needs to be replaced by IF-statements without ELSEs because you have a multi-select and you need to check every value every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch only does 1 case, you want to always have them set to 0 first.

This should do that:

```
$firstItem = ($value == 1) ? 1 : 0;
$anotherItem = ($value == 2) ? 1 : 0;
$thirdItem = ($value == 3) ? 1 : 0;
```

The default case only runs if the `$value` isn't 1, 2, or 3, which is why you were getting nulls.  Also, a switch only follows one branch (or one branch and all subsequent branches if there is no break) so you should us if statements or tertiary statements as above.  If you can have true/false as your variable value (rather than 1/0) you can just do `$firstitem = ($value == 1);`

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes, now my code is updating, but only one value, If I select two values or more, sql updates only one row

Comment: Actually, not breaking will always fall through, so a selection of 1 would always result in all 3 being set to 1.  I'll update.  In this case, you just need 3 if statements.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show where you get `$value`, but you need a `select` and it needs a `name` defined as an array `[]` to get the multiple values in an array on the PHP side. Then it would be easier just to set those array values to `1`.

```
<select name="something[]" multiple>
    <option value="1">First selection item</option>
    <option value="1">Another selection item</option>
    <option value="1">Third selection item</option>
</select>
```

So now you can create a default array of `0`s and `$nickname`, replace with the array from the select, and then use in the `execute`:

```
$params = array_replace(array(0,0,0,$nickname), $_POST['something']);
$stmt->execute( $params );
```

Comment: Good solution! :-)